# Electron App node-integration : How to access require() after POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building an electron app and have run into a problem with require being undefined when a page POSTs to itself. My goal is to use electron as a wrapper around an existing site that, unfortunately has this post behavior. After lots of trial and error with preload and executeJavascript I found using require() and node-integration worked. That is unless the request is POST. I am pretty new to Electron and node, so maybe I'm just missing something simple!

I get this behavior in Electron 0.26.0 and 0.27.1.

Here is the simplest way to recreate the issue.

*package.json*

```
{
"name": "PostExample",
"version": "0.1.0",
"main": "main.js",
"description": "Post Loses Global"
}
```

*main.js*

```
var app = require('app')
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    app.quit()
});

app.on('ready', function() {

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
        "node-integration": true,
    });

    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html')

    mainWindow.openDevTools()

});
```

*index.html*

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(typeof global)
    try{
        var fs = require("fs");
    } catch(e){
        console.warn("ERROR", e)
    }
 </script>
<body>
 <h1>Posts to self</h1>
 <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="somevar" value="val" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created an issue in github. The response was "Node integration relies on Chromium's browser-side-navigation feature, which doesn't support POST requests yet" - https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1959.

Comment: Hello, what about now on 2018?

Comment: It has been fixed. Seems like a long time ago. Just tested w/ electron 1.4.13 and it is working.